# VS code opens Jupyter notebook in weird form

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using VS code with Jupyter notebook extension for python version 3.8.

When I open the any file with .ipynb by double clicking it, vs code shows the file in weird form like below.

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# import functions"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 3,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import numpy as np"
   ]
  },
  {
```

However, I open same files with File>Open File... then it shows normal form of Jupyter notebook, which has separate cells.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image]

- I'm using Mac

Comment: It seems that the code wasn't rendered successfully. What's your current used python and Jupyter extension version?

Comment: @MollyWang I'm using several python versions with pyenv. but It happens with all python version. Version isn't a problem I think... Jupyter version is v2021.6.832593372. It did not happened before, but after my Mac shut down kind of forcibly, the problem occurs. I already reinstall vscode, but even after the re installation, it's still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Jupyter in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_trusted-notebooks):

> When a Notebook is Not Trusted, VS Code will not render Markdown cells
> or display the output of code cells within the Notebook. Instead, just
> the source of Markdown and code cells will be shown.

Open the .ipynb file from **File--> Open File** to check if its status is **Not Trusted**:

[image]

You can relaunch the trust notification prompt after reviewing the Notebook by clicking on the **Not Trusted** status, then choose **Trust**.

**[UPDATE]**

Change the `"cell_type"` from `markdown` to `code`.

Comment: When I open the .ipynb through File--> Open File, it works fine always. However, it shows just the source of Markdown when I open the file by double clicking the file. In that case I can not see the "Not Trusted" "Jupyter Server" etc. I updated the screen shot

Comment: When you open the .ipynb through File--> Open File, the status is **Trust**?

Comment: Yes. When I open the .ipynb through that, It's normal and the status is Trust

Comment: How about creating a new Jupyter Notebook then saving it as .ipynb file? Is it still not rendered successfully when you reopen .ipynb file?

Comment: @Dong-gyunKim. I checked my .ipynb file and found all its cell_type was `code`. So please change it to code in the ipynb file then see if it solves your question.

Comment: If it still does not work, can you share your .ipynb in github if convenient? I'll follow up to do further research.

Comment: I solve this issue my self. It seems there's problem with linking python env and vs code. therefore I will close this question. Many thanks :)